# DO3THINK USB camera install into raspberrypi

Tags: raspbian, camera, motion

Actually, I am using USB2.0 DO3THINK camera for personal purposes.
I want to connect this camera to my raspberry pi.
I research it but couldn't find any proper link for install this camera.
The os system in which I am using Raspbian. Even I tried to use it in motionEye OS still it did not show in the "add camera" list.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04b4:ea02 Cypress Semiconductor Corp.
001 Device 004: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
```

The camera is the first entry.

Comment: Edit in the output from `lsusb`.  You may need to `sudo apt install usbutils` first.

Comment: I already update all the libraries. Even, I checked this lib. which has the newest version. when I type command lsusb. it prints like,
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04b4:ea02 Cypress Semiconductor Corp.  <== this device, which I want to install in my raspberry pi Bus 
001 Device 004: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.

Comment: After you plugin the camera, what does the `dmesg` command say? Usually if a USB device is properly detected it should list what module has claimed it.